# how to set an element to be required webmethods caf using javascript

Tags: webmethods, webmethods-caf

I want to set `required=true` of an input in caf webmethods using javascript.

this my code that I try to set required:

```
if (CAF.model('#{activePageBean.clientIds['dropDowntypeFlux']}').getValue() == 'expo'){
     CAF.model('#{activePageBean.clientIds['htmlInputMatricule']}').setAttribute("required", "true");
}
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try using CAF.model().element to get the original HTML Element:

```
if (CAF.model('#{activePageBean.clientIds['dropDowntypeFlux']}').element.getValue() == 'expo'){
 CAF.model('#activePageBean.clientIds['htmlInputMatricule']}').element.setAttribute("required", "true");
}
```

With CAF.model() you are using a JavaScript CAF Object with other features.